# Changing height of individual cell UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I would like something like the following:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("NewsCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    if indexPath == 3{

        cell.height = "50dp"

    }       

    return cell

}
```

what is the alternative or the easiest way to go about this?

**EDIT**

Is it possible for me to also specify section number: i.e-

```
if sectionIndex == 5
```

Comment: Read table view delegate protocol reference..

Answer (score 26):

I suggest use the **heightForRowAtIndexPath** function. TableView will call this function to determine the row height for a specific indexpath.

Sample code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.section == SECTION_INDEX {
        return 60
    } else {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
}
```

Swift 4:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.section == SECTION_INDEX {
        return 60
    } else {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
}
```

A little explain:
indexPath have two properties: section and row. By checking these two properties, you can make your own control flow to determine the height for each cell.

If you return 60, it means you want the cell's height to be 60 points. If you return UITableViewAutomaticDimension, you want the system to decide the best height for you (in this case, you'd better set autolayout for the cell in storyboard).

I also suggest you take the stanford course CS193p on iTunes U, it would be of great help to you :)

Comment: This forces you to set the height for cells you might want to leave unchanged...I think thats why Moritz hasn't selected an answer.

Answer (score 11):

the easiest way is to override `heightForRowAtIndexPath`

```
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let section = indexPath.section
    let row = indexPath.row
    if section == 0 && row == 2{
      return 50.0
    }
    return 22.0
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat{
   if indexPath.section == 5
   {
       if indexPath.row == 3
       {
           return 150.0
       }
   }

   return 200.0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following Zhu Shengqi's answer, here is the Swift 5+ code.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if indexPath.section == SECTION_INDEX {
            return 160
        } else {
            return UITableView.automaticDimension
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is to override heightForRowAtIndexPath delegate method is there in tableview.
These method based on content it will change the height automatically.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    
    return UITableView.AutoDiemensions
  }
```