# How to make a particular static cell in UItableview self adjusting according to the constraints of the contents inside it

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview

I've done some research on self adjusting static cells but they seem to apply to the entire table view as a whole.

what if I'm only interested in targeting a specific cell like the picture below? How do I go about doing it?

[image]

edit: What I intend is for the tableview cell to expand when the collectionview gets populated with more cells. Thus allowing the entire page to scroll accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the images in the collection view always the same height ?  If the images in the view are a static size, you could just divide the number of images, by the number that will fit on a line. Then multiply that by the height of the lines to set the tableview cell height.

This might be helpful:
[Dynamic Sized Tableview Cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31155795/changing-height-of-individual-cell-uitableview-swift)