# Cannot change the row height of TableViewCells - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nstableviewcell

I am attempting to set the height of a custom `tableViewCell`, but the code below does not work. What is the better way to do this?

**Programmatically:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  self.tableView.rowHeight = 140
}
```

**via storyboard:**

1. Selected on `tableView` -> `size Inspector` -> set `row height` to 140.

**I have also tried the following:**

2. Selected the custom `UITableViewCell` -> `size Inspector` -> set `row height` to 140.

Comment: Take a look here - https://stackoverflow.com/q/31155795/2908082

Comment: You don't need to implement delegate method if you have same height for all the rows. You can do this through storyboard https://stackoverflow.com/a/46519806/4272498

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you are using UITableViewController like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 140.0
}
```

if you are using UIViewController, you must implement UITableViewDelegate

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 140.0
}
```